# How to do replace multiple times ? php

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace, php-5.3

I want to replace `word1` with `word2` and `word2` with `word1` for this string :

```
word1 word2
```

here is what i want to do :

1.replace word1 with word2 => I get : word2 word2

2.replace word2 with word1 => I should get word2 word1 .

but I get this : 
`word1 word1` becuase str_replace function also replace the first replaced word1.

How to avoid this kind of problems ?

thanks

Comment: Use [strtr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead of [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Why don't you `explode()` your string and switch the words?

Comment: @Daan could you write your answer , i don't understand your solution . thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker do you think strtr will be effective for long strings. 500 char with 20 replacement ?

Comment: strtr() is PHP's built-in function that was designed to do exactly what you're asking.... Do you have any reason to believe that it won't be effective? that it might be buggy or something? It's core PHP, so it's written in C, and has unit tests to prove that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this by str_replace. Use string translation (strtr) which was designed to do so instead:

```
$words = 'word1 word2';
$wordsReplaced = strtr($words, [
    'word1' => 'word2',
    'word2' => 'word1'
]);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but do you think strtr will be effective for long strings. 500 char with 20 replacement ?

Comment: Well, str_replace is about two times faster, but form the other hand 500 chars is not a big deal. And you rather do not have an option here. I use strtr in high-performance ad serving app and it doing well.